# Azure Front Door decompressing assets

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-front-door

I have an Azure web app running an Angular with NGINX inside a Docker container. This is fronted by Azure Front Door.
The Nginx config has the following at the beginning to enable compression:

```
server {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types *;
```

When hitting the webapp directly, this works fine

However, when hitting the webapp via AFD, the assets aren't compressed, so it looks like AFD is doing something to decompress the assets. Caching is disabled for the entire AFD instance.

I'm not much of a frontend guy, and this work is part of a larger overhaul of the project, so any help would be appreciated. If I need to give more info, let me know.

Tl;dr: Hitting a webapp directly honours the Nginx compression configuration. Hitting the webapp via AFD does not. Why?

Comment: Azure Front Door can dynamically compress content on the edge.  Caching must be enabled and the file must be of a MIME type to be eligible for compression

Answer (score 0):

Azure Front Door can dynamically compress content on the edge. **Caching must be enabled,** and the file must be of a MIME type to be eligible for compression.  Need to enable caching behavior by the time of creation “Front Door”
[image]

Please select “Use Query String” if require

[image]
refer:  [Troubleshoot Azure Front Door common issues | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/troubleshoot-issues)

Comment: Yes but I don't want Azure FD to do it. I want Nginx to do it and I don't understand why FD is seemingly undoing the compression applied by Nginx.